# Using multiple variables for single neo4j node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, cypher-shell

I have a cypher query that returns some results

```
MATCH (nodeFrom0:Z{})-[r1:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo1:A{})
MATCH (nodeTo1:A{})-[r2:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo2:A{})
MATCH (nodeTo2:A{})-[r3:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo3:A{})
MATCH (nodeTo3:A{})-[r4:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo4:B{})
MATCH (nodeTo4:B{})-[r5:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo5:C{})
MATCH (nodeTo5:C{})-[r6:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo6:B{})
MATCH (nodeTo4:B{})-[r7:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo7:D{})
MATCH (nodeTo7:D{})-[r8:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo6:B{})
MATCH (nodeTo6:B{})-[r9:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo8:E{})

RETURN nodeFrom0, nodeTo1, nodeTo2, nodeTo3, nodeTo4, nodeTo5, nodeTo6, nodeTo7, nodeTo8
```

But I dont want to reuse a variable name, and identify the same nodes based on Id and use a new variable, How can I do that

Tried

```
MATCH (nodeFrom0:Z{}) -[nodeRelation0:FLOWS_TO]-> (nodeTo0:A{})
MATCH (nodeFrom1:A{id: nodeTo0.id}) -[nodeRelation1:FLOWS_TO]-> (nodeTo1:A{})
MATCH (nodeFrom2:A{id: nodeTo1.id}) -[nodeRelation2:FLOWS_TO]-> (nodeTo2:A{})
MATCH (nodeFrom3:A{id: nodeTo2.id}) -[nodeRelation3:FLOWS_TO]-> (nodeTo3:B{})
MATCH (nodeFrom4:B{id: nodeTo3.id}) -[nodeRelation4:FLOWS_TO]-> (nodeTo4:C{})
MATCH (nodeFrom5:C{id: nodeTo4.id}) -[nodeRelation5:FLOWS_TO]-> (nodeTo5:B{})
MATCH (nodeFrom6:B{id: nodeTo5.id}) -[nodeRelation6:FLOWS_TO]-> (nodeTo6:D{})
MATCH (nodeFrom7:D{id: nodeTo6.id}) -[nodeRelation7:FLOWS_TO]-> (nodeTo7:B{})
MATCH (nodeFrom8:B{id: nodeTo7.id}) -[nodeRelation8:FLOWS_TO]-> (nodeTo8:E{})
return nodeFrom0,nodeRelation0,nodeTo0,nodeFrom1,nodeRelation1,nodeTo1,nodeFrom2,nodeRelation2,nodeTo2,nodeFrom3,nodeRelation3,nodeTo3,nodeFrom4,nodeRelation4,nodeTo4,nodeFrom5,nodeRelation5,nodeTo5,nodeFrom6,nodeRelation6,nodeTo6,nodeFrom7,nodeRelation7,nodeTo7,nodeFrom8,nodeRelation8,nodeTo8
```

Here basically id of nodeTo1 and nodeFrom2 are same eventually nodes are same. But my second query doesn't return any result.

The reason being, I am generating this query reading a json of relations, [{node1:xxxx, relation:xxxx, node2:xxxx},{node1:xxxx, relation:xxxx, node2:xxxx}]

so if the Id of node2 of one json matches the id of node1 I can treat it as same node, but with different variable name, coz it will be code generated

And The cypher query from this should also return the similar form output.

Comment: Are you wanting the `Id()` of the node, or do you have a property called `id`?

Comment: Yes I want the ```Id()``` of node

Answer (score 1):

Generating independent relationship queries (as in you second query) causes inefficient Cypher, since you would have to scan for the same start/end nodes multiple times. That is not a "graphy" approach. Instead, it would be much faster to preprocess the raw data so that you generate Cypher that reuses the nodes already found, allowing neo4j to quickly leverage relationships to find subsequent nodes in a path (without any scanning).

What you want to generate is something similar to this:

```
MATCH
  (nodeFrom0:Z)
  -[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo1:A{id: 1})
  -[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo2:A{id: 2})
  -[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo3:A{id: 3})
  -[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo4:B{id: 4})
  -[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo5:C{id: 5})
  -[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo6:B{id: 6}),
  (nodeTo4)
  -[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo7:D{id: 7})
  -[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo6)
  -[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo8:E{id: 8})
RETURN nodeFrom0, nodeTo1, nodeTo2, nodeTo3, nodeTo4, nodeTo5, nodeTo6, nodeTo7, nodeTo8
```

or at least this:

```
MATCH
  (nodeFrom0:Z)-[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo1:A{id: 1}),
  (nodeTo1)-[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo2:A{id: 2}),
  (nodeTo2)-[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo3:A{id: 3}),
  (nodeTo3)-[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo4:B{id: 4}),
  (nodeTo4)-[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo5:C{id: 5}),
  (nodeTo5)-[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo6:B{id: 6}),
  (nodeTo4)-[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo7:D{id: 7}),
  (nodeTo7)-[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo6),
  (nodeTo6)-[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo8:E{id: 8})
RETURN nodeFrom0, nodeTo1, nodeTo2, nodeTo3, nodeTo4, nodeTo5, nodeTo6, nodeTo7, nodeTo8
```

Here is another approach that returns [paths](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/queries/concepts/#core-concepts-paths), which include both nodes and relationships:

```
MATCH
  p1=(nodeFrom0:Z)
  -[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo1:A{id: 1})
  -[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo2:A{id: 2})
  -[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo3:A{id: 3})
  -[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo4:B{id: 4})
  -[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo5:C{id: 5})
  -[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo6:B{id: 6}),
  p2=(nodeTo4)
  -[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo7:D{id: 7})
  -[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo6)
  -[:FLOWS_TO]->(nodeTo8:E{id: 8})
RETURN p1, p2
```

Comment: I do not intend to use the same variables even if the same node is repeated.
However, if this is the query, how can I get the returned json in the form of nodeStart, relation, nodeEnd for all the relations and nodes.

For eg. the returns received by the Query Match (a)-[r]->(b) return a,r,b

Comment: It should not be hard to generate Cypher to reuse variables, and you would end up with simpler and faster Cypher. There are many ways to return the relationships. The simplest is add a unique variable to each relationship (e.g., `r12` for the relationship from `nodeTo1` to `nodeTo2`), and include `r12` as a return value. Or, you could consider returning separate [paths](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/queries/concepts/#core-concepts-paths), which include both nodes and relationships (your result can be broken down into 2 paths). I have added an example with paths to my answer.